# Turn off JSON deserialization of results from spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

We pull many large-ish payloads from Spanner, and the current performance bottleneck is deserializing the result from Spanner into objects in memory. We don't need these objects, as the result is just going to pass through to another application. I haven't seen anything in the SDK documentation about this, but I'm sure there is a way to provide a custom deserialization, or to turn it off altogether. We currently use the Javascript and Java SDKs, so any advice on either is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Benjamin, would you mind adding a little more detail as to exactly what part is eating most CPU, and/or what the most desirable outcome would be? The header says '...JSON deserialization...', but the client libraries use gRPC, which again uses a binary protocol. Still, many values are encoded as strings, and some of these are converted into objects (e.g. Timestamp). Would your use case for example be helped if you could access the underlying string value of such query results?

Answer (score 0):

#### Node.js

The Node.js client by default does not serialize the query results. Instead, you either need to set `json: true` on the query that is executed, or call `row.toJSON()` on an unserialized row to serialize a query result. See https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/blob/5e407c071a69f5ef39e7277671e4393cb12f44b8/samples/crud.js#L217 for an example.

#### Java

**NOTE**: The below lazy behavior was introduced after this question was originally asked. The original behavior of the client when this question was asked was that all columns were eagerly deserialized, and hence a likely cause for this question to be asked in the first place.

The Java client will serialize most of the lightweight types by default when a row is read, but not `BYTES` columns. The latter is the one that can require a decent amount of CPU to deserialize. The following applies to `BYTES` columns in the Java client:

1. They are only deserialized when the `ResultSet#getBytes(..)` method is called.
2. You can also get a `BYTES` column as a string by calling `ResultSet#getString(..)` on a `BYTES` column, which will return the underlying `Base64` string representation that was returned by Cloud Spanner. This is the representation that Cloud Spanner uses for network transport, meaning that no (de-)serialization is needed to get this value. This can give a significant reduction in CPU usage for clients that only read `BYTES` columns with the intention of writing them to some other system (e.g. exporting them to a CSV file).

In addition, the following is also supported by the Java client:

- Calling `ResultSet#getValue(..)` will return the gRPC value that was returned by Cloud Spanner. This method is safe to call for all data types, including for columns that contain a null value. Calling this method will not cause any (de-)serialization to happen. The `Value` instance that is returned supports a `Value#getAsString()` which returns a string representation of that `Value`. This method is also guaranteed to work for all data types, and to return a non-truncated, valid value for the underlying type.